# How to view all plots in Ghost Script view

Tags: ghostscript

I am working with different plots created using the script running in octave. Earlier i used irfanview to view all the plots. But somehow now Irfanview can't output the quality so i am turning to GS view as it can handle vectors better. The problem i am facing is that i cannot just scroll through all the plots in one folder in Gs view as i used to do in Irfanview. I have to drag and drop each file to open the plot. Is there a way that i can simply scroll through files in GS view. All the plots are in same folder.

Comment: GSView isn't Ghostscript, it simply **uses** Ghostscript. It's also very old and not really maintained. I don't know of any way to do what you want with it. You could supply each file to Ghostscript on the command line (using the display device). If each file is a single page then when you press return it will move on to the next file.

Comment: The main Problem is that my output is .eps and there are not many open source solution available. All i want to do is view the results without opening each file separately. In Irfanview it is like you just click next and it displays the next file/plot in the folder. In GS view i would have to open each file separately, irrespective of if it's in same folder or not. I am talking about atleast 20 folders with 5 files each. The plots are generated on daily basis. All i am looking for is an eps viewer that works as normal explorer.

Comment: As I said, if you supply each file in sequence to Ghostscript on the command line it will draw each file in turn. Of course, the display is simple, but then it's not intended to be anything else. Alternatively you could use Ghostscript to render each file to an image and use your favourite image viewer to inspect those any way you like. Or you can write your own image viewer, delegating the rendering of the PostScript to Ghostscript. The reason there are not many open source solutions for PostScript are that it's an old language and it's a hard problem.